# Swift3: How to use user default data in NSArray?

Tags: ios, swift, textview, swift3, nsuserdefaults

I have created a user default property called "data", which holds values of `String`, meaning it is an array of String. And I want to use Strings in the "data" as `searchString` written below`("one", "two", "three")`. I have created a method;

```
func getInput() -> [String] {
    if let myData = userDefaults.array(forKey: "data") as? [String] {
        return myData
    }
    return []
}
```

And I put the code inside `NSArray.init()`, which looked like inside`NSArray.init(getInput)`. However, an error came out, saying something like it is not NSArray, so I think it is the problem.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: mytextView.text)
    let inputLength = attrStr.string.characters.count
    let searchString : NSArray = NSArray.init("one", "two", "three")
    for i in 0...searchString.count-1 {
        let string : String = searchString.object(at: i) as! String
        let searchLength = string.characters.count
        var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.length)
        while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            range = (attrStr.string as NSString).range(of: string, options: [], range: range)
            if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                range = NSRange(location: range.location + range.length, length: inputLength - (range.location + range.length))
                mytextView.attributedText = attrStr
            }
        }
    }
```

Also if there is a better way to save data from users rather than user defaults, could you tell me why and sample too. But my main issue is how to access user default saved data and put the data into the`NSArray.init("*here*")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift it is batter if you use Swift native `Array` and `Dictionary` instead of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`, but to answer your question you can initialize `NSArray` with Swift type Array using initializer `NSArray(array:)`.

```
let searchString : NSArray = NSArray.init(array: getInput())
```

Or

```
let searchString : NSArray = NSArray(array: getInput())
```

Comment: It is so simple a solution. Thanks